# LifeCoach project

Tags: java, beginner

This project is about helping people with common problems like "Partner dumped me" or "I hate my job", recommending self-help books for every problem and specific person according to age and gender.

Can anybody suggest improvements for my project? How can I make this an actual useful project?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // VARIABLES
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean young = false;
        boolean youngadult = false;
        boolean adult = false;
        boolean elder = false;
        boolean male = false;
        boolean female = false;

        // GENDER
        System.out.print("What's your gender? (M/F) ");
        String gender = scanner.nextLine();
        if (gender.equals("M") || gender.equals("m")) {
            male = true;
        } else if (gender.equals("F") || gender.equals("f")) {
            female = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // AGE
        System.out.print("What's your age? ");
        int age = scanner.nextInt();
        if (age < 16) {
            System.out.println("Sorry you must be at least 16 years old.");
        } else if (age < 18) {
            young = true;
        } else if (age < 30) {
            youngadult = true;
        } else if (age < 65) {
            adult = true;
        } else if (age < 120) {
            elder = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // OPTIONS
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Choose your problem:");
        System.out.println("1. My partner dumped me.");
        System.out.println("2. I can't find a partner.");
        System.out.println("3. I am getting old.");
        System.out.println("4. My bills are overwhelming me.");
        System.out.println("5. I hate my job.");
        System.out.println("6. My partner is driving me crazy.");
        System.out.println("7. I think my partner is seeing someone else.");
        System.out.println("8. My partner is addicted to drugs or alcohol.");

        // CHOICE
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        if (choice < 1 || choice > 8) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("");

        // SWITCH CHOICE
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            if (female && young) {
                System.out.println("Recommended book: The Breakup Bible, by Melissa Kantor.");
            } else if (female && youngadult || adult || elder) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Recommended book: The Breakup Bible: The Smart Woman’s Guide to Healing From a Breakup or Divorce, by Rachel Sussman");
            } else if (male) {
                System.out.println("Recommended book: The Power of Now, by Eckhart Tolle.");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (female) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Recommended book: And She Lived Happily Ever After: Finding Fulfillment as a Single Woman, by Skip McDonald.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(
                        "Recommended book: Never Be Lonely Again: The Way Out of Emptiness, Isolation, and a Life Unfulfilled, by Pat Love and Jon Carlson.");
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (female) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Recommended book: Rebellious Aging: A Self-help Guide for the Old Hippie at Heart, by Margaret Nash.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(
                        "Recommended book: Younger Next Year: Live Strong, Fit, and Sexy - Until You're 80 and Beyond, by Chris Crowley.");
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (youngadult) {
                System.out.println("Recommended book: I Will Teach You To Be Rich, by Ramit Sethi.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Recommended book: The Millionaire Next Door, by Stanley and Danko.");
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Recommended book: How to Better Hate Your Job, by Egbert Sukop.");
            break;
        case 6:
            if (female && young || youngadult) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Recommended book: Deal Breakers: When to Work On a Relationship and When to Walk Away, by Dr. Bethany Marshall.");
            } else if (male && young || youngadult) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Recommended book: The Five Love Languages: The Secret to Love that Lasts, by Gary D Chapman.");
            } else if (female && adult || elder) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Recommended book: Too Good to Leave, Too Bad to Stay: A Step-by-Step Guide to Help You Decide Whether to Stay In or Get Out of Your Relationship, by Mira Kirshenbaum.");
            } else if (male && adult || elder) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Recommended book: Love, Sex and Staying Warm: Creating a Vital Relationship, by Neil Rosenthal.");
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            if (female) {
                System.out.println("Recommended book: Life Without Jealousy: A Practical Guide, by Lynda Bevan.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Recommended book: The Wisdom of Insecurity, by Alan Watts.");
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.println(
                    "Recommended book: Coping With An Addict: Ways of Dealing With an Addict Spouse, Family Member, Friend or Loved One, by JC Anonymous.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have _The One Answer_ for any kind of problem?

Answer (score 6):

#### Methods

You put your entire program in the `main` method.  A better practice is to break up the program into multiple blocks.  Then your `main` method might look like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LifeCoach coach = new LifeCoach();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            coach.inputGender();
            coach.inputAge();
            coach.inputChoice();
        }

        coach.recommend();
    }
```

This also uses the [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to automatically close the `Scanner` when it's finished using it.

There is an argument that you should separate input, logic, and display.  Here, we do all three in the `LifeCoach` class.  Further, the logic is embedded in the same methods that do input and display. That's not ideal from a separation of concerns perspective, but in such a small program it may not be worth engineering it more.

#### `enum` vs. `boolean`

> ```
>         boolean young = false;
>         boolean youngadult = false;
>         boolean adult = false;
>         boolean elder = false;
>         boolean male = false;
>         boolean female = false;
> ```

Rather than use six `boolean` values, consider using two [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) values.

```
public enum AgeCategory {
    YOUNG, YOUNG_ADULT, ADULT, ELDER
}

public enum Gender {
    FEMALE, MALE
}
```

#### `equalsIgnoreCase`

> ```
>         if (gender.equals("M") || gender.equals("m")) {
>             male = true;
>         } else if (gender.equals("F") || gender.equals("f")) {
>             female = true;
> ```

Java has a method just for this situation

```
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("M")) {
            gender = MALE;
        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
            gender = FEMALE;
```

Now we don't have to write out each case.  Or you can use a [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html):

```
        switch (scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase()) {
        case "M":
            gender = MALE;
            break;
        case "F":
            gender = FEMALE;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

#### Simplify

> ```
>             if (female && young) {
>                 System.out.println("Recommended book: The Breakup Bible, by Melissa Kantor.");
>             } else if (female && youngadult || adult || elder) {
>                 System.out.println(
>                         "Recommended book: The Breakup Bible: The Smart Woman’s Guide to Healing From a Breakup or Divorce, by Rachel Sussman");
>             } else if (male) {
>                 System.out.println("Recommended book: The Power of Now, by Eckhart Tolle.");
>             }
> ```

In each of these, you follow the same pattern.  Consider

```
    public void recommend() {
        System.out.println("Recommended book: " + determineRecommendation());
    }
```

Then the `switch` statement gets simpler.

```
    public String determineRecommendation() {
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            if (gender == MALE) {
                return "The Power of Now, by Eckhart Tolle.";
            } else if (ageCategory == YOUNG) {
                return "The Breakup Bible, by Melissa Kantor.";
            } else {
                return "The Breakup Bible: The Smart Woman’s Guide to Healing From a Breakup or Divorce, by Rachel Sussman.";
            }
```

Here we just return a string representing the book title and author.

Note that with this order, it's easier to write out the criteria.  Either male or not male (female).  Two female possibilities.  One for the young and one for everyone else.  The `else` represents female and young adult, adult, or elder.  This is the same as the original, but with less writing.

This also shows how use of the `enum` values differs from the original `boolean` values.

#### A database

Now, if you want to switch to a database, you just need to change the `enum` definitions and `determineRecommendation`.  The input collection can stay the same.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this. Instead understand why the warning is there and handle it appropriately.

`@SuppressWarnings("resource")`

In this case, calling `scanner.close();` at the end of your code is enough to solve it the real way.

---

Instead of `gender.equals("M") || gender.equals("m")` you can use the method `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare in a case-insensitive way. Another approach is also to do `gender.toLowerCase().equals("m")` but I would recommend to use `equalsIgnoreCase`.

---

Your checks for invalid input are good, but I would recommend avoiding using `System.exit(0);` to shut down your program. Either use a non-zero exit code to indicate there was a problem, like `System.exit(1);`, or simply do `return;` to end your `main` method and therefore also your program.

Also, it seems like if a user is under 16 then they will be able to choose a problem still.

```
if (age < 16) {
    System.out.println("Sorry you must be at least 16 years old.");
}
```

---

Now for the interesting parts, deciding which book to display.

Your main logic for giving the right book suggestion has some logic paths that are a bit hard to read and understand when they will happen. I would highly recommend avoid combining `&&` and `||` on the same `if` without using parenthesis.

Now, what if you want to recommend multiple books in some cases? Then you can just copy and change the `System.out.println` statement, right? Yes, you can. However, it is not easy at the moment to maintain a list of books and specifying which book to apply in which situation.

---

Now I will introduce some concepts that you are not used to yet, see this as a "This is what you will learn and what is possible". This is very likely to be above your skill level at the moment, but it might be interesting for you to hear about it.

What if we assign logic for each book to know when it is applicable? Let's see how we can model our problem.

Let's have a class, `Book`. And a class `Person`.

```
class Book {
    public String description;
    public Predicate<Person> applicable; // needs `java.util.function.Predicate`
}

class Person {
    public int age;
    public String gender; // `F` or `M`
    public int problem;
}
```

(Later you will also learn about constructors, getters and setters, and other stuff)

With this approach, you can have a `List<Book>` where each book knows if it is applicable or not.

For example:

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

Book book = new Book();
book.description = "The Breakup Bible, by Melissa Kantor.";
book.applicable = person -> person.problem == 1 && person.female && person.young;
books.add(book);
// TODO: Add more books here...
```

Here we are specifying logic in `book.applicable` by using a "lambda", which is available since Java 8.

Now you can create a `Person` object and use a *loop* to find out which book(s) should be recommended.

```
for (Book theBook : books) {
    if (theBook.applicable.test(person)) {
        System.out.println("Recommended book: " + theBook.description);
    }
}
```

---

Oh, and by the way... as I've already introduced more advanced topics, let me just say that by using Machine Learning your problem would be handled even better, and would be how today's real world book recommendation systems work. "Collaborative filtering Recommendation System" is a concept that are used by the big companies out there. "Logistic Regression" is also something that could be applied in this scenario.

---

Keep learning.